# How to prove that a 3-connected 5-regular planar graph has chromatic number <= 4?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I can think of a way that to prove a 3-connected 5-regular planar graph does not contain a 5-critical subgraph.

We can choose two non-adjacent vertices a,b and contract them into a single vertex. If a and b has common neighbours, the resultant graph will still be a planar graph G'. But how can I prove chromatic number of G' is less or equal than 4?

Furthermore, how to prove that a 5-regular planar graph has chromatic number <= 4?

Comment: This is not quite a research-level question.

Comment: It makes sense to me to ask for a short proof that every 5-regular planar graph is 4-colorable. All known proofs of 4CT use computers, including the proofs that follow after Appel, Koch and Haken's proof. The answerers who claim otherwise are mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Every planar graph can be colored by 4 color, take dual of graph, the faces of dual are able to be colored by 4 color because of 4 color theorem, but they are also vertices of original graph.

Comment: But we need computers to prove 4-color thm, right?
What I want is a human-doable proof to this weaker problem.

Comment: @nuk, We don't need to invent a wheel, 4 color theorem is a famous theorem and we don't need to prove it. But if you looking for non computer proof, take a look at seymour etal proof, here you can find a brief overview by one of a authors (Robin Thomas): http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/FC/fourcolor.html

Comment: As Tommy Jensen mentions below, even this second-generation proof of Robertson, Sanders, Seymour and Thomas uses computer verification, albeit a shorter a more trustworthy one. Recently Gonthier and his team came up with a completely formalized computer-aided proof, which should remove any doubts regarding the correctness of the previous proofs. Another computer-aided proof is due to John Steinberger: http://iiis.tsinghua.edu.cn/~john/4c.pdf.